# Python/Pygame - IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, pygame

I'm trying to program a minesweeper game with pygame and I want to show all the bombs when I click on one of them :

```
bouttonbomb = pygame.image.load("bouttonbomb.jpg").convert()
    for x in range(0, nbpixel, cellsize):
        for y in range(0, nbpixel, cellsize):
            if grille[x][y] == BOMB:
                fenetre.blit(bouttonbomb, (x, y))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

but I got this error : `IndexError: list index out of range`

on this line :

`if grille[x][y] == BOMB:`

So I don't understand, why ?

Comment: I take a wild guess: `range(0, nbpixel, cellsize)` is sth. like  `[0, 100, 200, ...]` while for `grille[x][y]`, you want it to be more like `[0, 1, 2, ...]`

Comment: Now you need to figure out what `x, y` you need in `blit` and adjust everything accordingly...

Comment: Yeah `range(0, nbpixel, cellsize)` is `[0, 20, 40, 60, ..., 400]` and I just want to check if the cell with the coordinates [x][y] is a bomb for display an image to these coordinates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `range(0, nbpixel, cellsize) is [0, 20, 40, 60, ..., 400]` and you want to check `coordinates [x][y]` then set `range(0, nbpixel/cellsize)` That way you are going to process each cell index.

```
bouttonbomb = pygame.image.load("bouttonbomb.jpg").convert()
    maxindex = nbpixel/cellsize
    for x in range(0, maxindex):
        for y in range(0, maxindex):
            if grille[x][y] == BOMB:
                fenetre.blit(bouttonbomb, (x, y))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: That looks like a valid approach :) now let's hope `blit` does not expect `x, y` to be from `[0, 20, ..., 400]`

Comment: Probably not, otherwise it would not have given you the index error. Most display programs work in this way. However, if it does not, then you just need to adjust the factor that you use.

Comment: lol why did someone downvote this answer. upvoted to cancel dumb downvote out, this answer is helpful.